# How to change the content of the layout?

Tags: java, android

In my Android application i have a tracker activity in which i retrieve the exercises information(name , period , burned calories) from the sqlite data base based on the selected date and display these information in a linear layout , and my problem that as the user select new date the retrieved data are displayed in another "new " layout appear above the old one but what actually i want to do is to display the new retrieved data on the same layout " change the layout content with the new retrieved data ", i have tried the remove all views method but it didn't work since the data appear for few minutes then dis appear

How i can do this: when the user select a new date the new retrieved data displayed on the same layout " refresh the old data by the new one " not to display them in anew layout . how i can do that ? please help me...

**java code**

```
  public class Tracker extends BaseActivity
  {  
private Button date_btn;
private ImageButton  left_btn;
private ImageButton  right_btn;
private ImageView    nodata;
private TextView ex_name;
private TextView ex_BCals;

private LinearLayout  excercises_LL;
private LinearLayout content_LL ;
private LinearLayout  notes;
private LinearLayout  details;  
private int year,month,day;
private double  tot_excals_burned;
private Calendar  localCalendar; 
private static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID=0;
private  boolean  has_ex_details;
private boolean  has_meal_details=false;
private Cursor exercises_cursor;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.tracker);




    date_btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_date);
    date_btn.setText(FormatDate());
    date_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            localCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
            year = localCalendar.get(1);
            month= localCalendar.get(2);
            day  =  localCalendar.get(5);
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });


    left_btn=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_left);
    left_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            localCalendar.add(5, -1);
            date_btn.setText(FormatDate(localCalendar,"EEEE, d/MMM/yyyy"));

            RefreshExercisesData();
            RefreshNoDataImage();
        }
    });

    right_btn=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_right) ;
    right_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            localCalendar.add(5, 1);
            date_btn.setText(FormatDate(localCalendar,"EEEE, d/MMM/yyyy"));

            RefreshExercisesData();
            RefreshNoDataImage();

        }
    });


    details=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll_details);
    notes=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll_notes);
    excercises_LL=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll_exercises);
    nodata=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.nodata_imgV);



    RefreshExercisesData();
    RefreshNoDataImage();


}


private String  FormatDate()
{   

    localCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    return new  SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, d/MMM/yyyy").format(localCalendar.getTime());

}

private String FormatDate(int year, int month, int day)
{   
    localCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    localCalendar.set(year, month, day);

    return new  SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, d/MMM/yyyy").format(localCalendar.getTime());
}

private String FormatDate(Calendar   calendar , String  format)
{

    return new  SimpleDateFormat(format).format(calendar.getTime());

}




private void RefreshExercisesData()
{   



    tot_excals_burned=0;

    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
    db.open();
    String selected_date= date_btn.getText().toString();
    Log.e("date", selected_date);


    exercises_cursor = db.getExerciseInfo(selected_date);

    if(exercises_cursor.getCount() !=0 )
    {

        has_ex_details=true;

        details.setVisibility(0);
        nodata.setVisibility(8);
        notes.setVisibility(0);

        //excercises_LL.removeAllViews();
        excercises_LL.setWeightSum(1.0F);
        excercises_LL.setVisibility(0);



        excercises_LL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        LayoutInflater exc_LayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService("layout_inflater");
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)exc_LayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tracker_header_item,null);
        TextView   tot_ex_cals_value=((TextView)(layout).findViewById(R.id.tv_tot_cals_value));
        TextView   exs_title=((TextView)(layout).findViewById(R.id.tv_item_title)) ;
        exs_title.setText("Exercises ");

        (layout).setPadding(0, 36, 0, 0);
        excercises_LL.addView((View)layout, 0);
        int i = 1;

        if (exercises_cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do 
            {
                content_LL=new LinearLayout(this);
                ex_name=new TextView(this);
                ex_name.setText( exercises_cursor.getFloat(1)+","  +exercises_cursor.getString(0) + "min ");
                ex_name.setTextColor(R.color.black);
                content_LL.addView(ex_name,0);

                ex_BCals=new TextView(this);
                ex_BCals.setText(Round(exercises_cursor.getFloat(2)) +" ");
                ex_BCals.setTextColor(R.color.color_black);
                content_LL.addView(ex_BCals,1);

                tot_excals_burned = tot_excals_burned+exercises_cursor.getFloat(2);

                excercises_LL.addView(content_LL, i);


                i++; 

            }
            while (exercises_cursor.moveToNext());

        }
        tot_ex_cals_value.setText(Round(tot_excals_burned) );

    }
    else if(exercises_cursor.getCount()==0 ||tot_excals_burned==0)
    {  

        has_ex_details=false;


        RefreshNoDataImage();

    }
    exercises_cursor.close();
    exercises_cursor.deactivate();
    db.close();

}


private void RefreshNoDataImage()
{    
    if(has_ex_details==false && has_meal_details==false)
    {       

        notes.setVisibility(8);
        excercises_LL.setVisibility(8);
        nodata.setImageResource(R.drawable.bg_nodata);
        nodata.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    }

    else
        nodata.setVisibility(8);


}




protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
{
    switch (id) {

    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, this.year, this.month, this.day);
    }
    return null;
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
{
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker paramDatePicker, int year, int monthofYear, int dayofMonth)
    {
        Tracker.this.year=year;
        month=monthofYear;
        day=dayofMonth;
        date_btn.setText(FormatDate(year,month,day));
        RefreshExercisesData();
        RefreshNoDataImage();

    }

};


private  String Round(double num) {
    return String.format("%.1f%n", num);

}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you defined these variables as static:

```
public static int icon;
public static String data_text;
public static String text;
```

**As a result only one instance of those variables are created for all instances of that class.** So when you create a new `Profile` each time, they are overwritten with new values. You need to remove the `static` keyword from variable declarations:

```
public int icon;
public String data_text;
public String text;
```

Then you cannot access them as static so you need to access like this:

```
 Profile pli = data[position];
 holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(pli.icon);
 holder.Datatxt.setText(pli.data_text);
 holder.txt.setText(pli.text);
```

Check out this if you want to learn more about `static`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: Iam trying  to do this : when the user click the list item the Activity level fore instance a dialog  will appear then the user will choose"update" his activity level , and then i want to put this value in the row_data ,its possible to do that? and how i can do it ?  i tried this approach                                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
profile_data[4]=new ProfileListItems(R.drawable.arrow_left,Activity_level[which],"ActivityLevel");  but it didnt work